# Laravel - Passing Request to Queue Job

Tags: php, laravel

I'm unable to pass a request to queue `handle()` job

```
 public function handle(Request $request)                                                                                                                                 |  package.json*
 {                                                                                                                                                                |  phpunit.xml*
     Log::alert('starting process');                                                                                                                              |  readme.md*
     Log::alert($request);                                                                                                                                        |  server.php*
                                                                                                                                                                  |~
     if (strpos($request->status, 'Approved') !== false) {                                                                                                        |~
         $name = Name::where('mId', '=', $request->mId)->get()->first();                                                                                          |~
                                                                                                                                                                  |~
         $client = new Client();                                                                                                                                  |~
                                                                                                                                                                  |~
         $client->request('POST', 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/email', [                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |~
             'json' => [                                                                                                                                          |~
                 'type' => $request->type,                                                                                                                        |~
                 'name' => $name->name,                                                                                                                  
             ]                                                                                                                                                    |~
         ]);                                                                                                                                                      |~
     }
```

As it is, `$request` comes empty. If I remove `Request` and only leave `handle($request)` I get this stack:

`Too few arguments to function App\Jobs\PostAlfred::handle(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected in`

I'm calling this function from the controller when the form is updated.

```
 public function update(UpdateRequest $request)                                                                                                                   |▸ vendor/
 {                                                                                                                                                                |  artisan*
     $redirect_location = parent::updateCrud($request);                                                                                                           |  composer.json*                                                                               |  composer.lock*
     PostMyJob::dispatch($request);
```

I tried adding `UpdateRequest`, such as this: `handle(UpdateRequest $request)`, then I get an authorization error.

Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: why does queue job need a request..? i believe the error caused by the fact, the job executed outside normal request flow.

Comment: Because this api calling makes the system hang. I need it to execute it asynchronously, and laravel comes with Queue, the only way to execute something async. If I don't, user will hang for a while when they click update because this process waits for the api call to finish.

Comment: well, i think you mixed up the concept for `queue` and `async` on other language. the queue is more akin of `cronjob`. i believe additional table will help you to store the required information for your queue.

Comment: Queue works fine. I don't need that code to be executed at that instant. And I have no idea what you talking about when you say additional table.. @BagusTesa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When you are passing any arguments to `dispatch` function, those are passed in the `constructor` of the job and not in `handle` method.

See document says [`The arguments passed to the dispatch method will be given to the job's constructor`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues)

In  your job do this :

```
class SomeJob extends Job{

  private $request;

  public function __construct(Request $request)
  {
    $this->request = $request;
  }

  public function handle()
  {
    if (strpos($this->request->status, 'Approved') !== false) {
         $name = Name::where('mId', '=', $this->request->mId)->get()->first();
         $client = new Client();
         $client->request('POST', 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/email', [
             'json' => [
                 'type' => $this->request->type,
                 'name' => $name->name,
             ]
         ]);
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Keep in mind that a request only exists in the context of an actual HTTP request. It exists only while your app is handling that request. There is no "request" when your queue worker starts taking jobs off of the queue. Laravel can't give you an instance of the request, because there is none.

What you'll need to do is explicitly pass the information your job requires in order to perform it's duty. If you just want the input of the request, you could do something like this - which will provide an array of input to the job's constructor.

```php
PostMyJob::dispatch($request->all())
```

```php
public function __construct(array $input)
{
    $this->input = $input;
}
```

You may have seen examples of Eloquent models being passed into a job, but don't let that fool you into thinking the whole class will be provided to the handler as-is. Laravel is smart enough to re-fetch the Eloquent model for you when it handles the job, but as described earlier it can't get the original request for you.

Comment: I tried this before. This is what I get doing this.. `Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Too few arguments to function App\Jobs\PostMyJob::handle(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected`